# Django filter through multiple fields in a many-to-many intermediary table

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-orm

I have the following models in my django project:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    media = models.ForeignKey(Media)

class Media(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    formats = models.ManyToManyField(Format,through='MediaFormat',related_name='media',blank=True)

class Format(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class MediaFormat(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField()
    format = models.ForeignKey(Format)
    media = models.ForeignKey(Media)
```

Now, I want to filter all videos which have a specific format, AND the status code for that format is 10 (ready to use). How can I do that?
(assuming that f is the format):

```
f = Format.objects.get(pk=3)
```

I'm tempted to use:

```
Video.objects.filter(media__formats=f, media__mediaformat__status=10)
```

But then, that would return all videos that matches both of these assumptions:

- a) contain that specific format, and
- b) contain any format with the status of 10

How am I supposed to filter only those who have that specific format in a status code of 10?

thank you!

Comment: FYI if you want to OR two query sets, I beleive you use `|` between the querysets. Not sure how helpful this is to OP but it should help others who come here.

Answer (score 18):

> Now, I want to filter all videos which have a specific format, AND the
> status code for that format is 10 (ready to use). How can I do that?
> (assuming that f is the format)

The code that you posted does exactly what you want:

```
Video.objects.filter(media__formats=f, media__mediaformat__status=10)
```

This is documented in [the `filter()` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter):

> Multiple parameters are joined via AND in the underlying SQL
> statement.

Answer (score 10):

You can chain the filters together for an "AND" construct.

Videos where the format is `f` AND the format's status is `10`

```
Video.objects.filter(media__formats=f).filter(media__mediaformat__status=10)
```

Comment: Not sure how that is different to the OP's suggestion:

Video.objects.filter(media__formats=f, media__mediaformat__status=10)

Comment: Actually it is different from OP suggestion, please look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships for your reference

Answer (score 3):

Probably not relevant for the OP, but might be for others like me who found this thread while searching for the right answer.

Ludwik got it right, but the section in the documentation that explains all of this, as well as how to do excludes, is in the [queries documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships).

Note that splitting the filter into two `filter` calls like Chris suggested will give you the exact opposite result: it will search for a video that has a media format `f` and that has a media format, not necessarily the same media format, with a status of 10.