# Filter django for objects containing subsets of same many to many relationship

Tags: django, django-queryset, python-3.5

In my database I have user objects with two many to many fields (messages and following) on them that both contain a many to many field related to another object Topic.

```
class User():
    messages = ManyToManyField('Message', related_name='users', blank=True, null=True)
    following = ForeignKey('Following', related_name='users', blank=True, null=True) 

class Message():
    date = DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    content = TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    topics = ManyToManyField('Topic', related_name='messages', blank=True, null=True)

class Following():
    name = CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    topics = ManyToManyField('Topic', related_name='following', blank=True, null=True)

class Topic():
    name = CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    source = CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to filter for all "users" who have "messages" attached to them that do not contain all of the topics attached to the "following" objects on the user.

Right now I am using a loop to accomplish this:

```
users = set()
for user in User.objects.filter(messages__isnull=False, following__isnull=False).iterator():
    if not set(user.following.values_list('topics', flat=True))
               ).issubset(set(user.messages.values_list('topics', flat=True)):
       users.add(user.pk)
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing with a single query?

---- EDIT ----

What I have is this:

```
User.objects.filter(following__isnull=False
).annotate(following_count=Count('following__topics', distinct=True)
).filter(following__topics__exact=F('message__topics')
).annotate(missing_topics=ExpressionWrapper(
    F('following_count') - Count('message__topics', distinct=True),
                                 IntegerField())
).filter(missing_topics__gt=0)
```

If there is a better way to do this or there are reasons why I should most definitely not do it this way, what are they?

---- EDIT ----

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489618/django-filter-through-multiple-fields-in-a-many-to-many-intermediary-table) helped me to understand and use [Håken Lid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52975791/6146607)

This is my new model and my new query:

```
class User():
    messages = ManyToManyField('Message', related_name='users', blank=True, null=True)
    following = ManyToManyField('Topic', through='Following', related_name='users', blank=True, null=True) 

class Message():
    date = DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    content = TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    topics = ManyToManyField('Topic', related_name='messages', blank=True, null=True)

class Following():
    name = CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    user = ForeignKey('User', related_name='following', blank=True, null=True)
    topic = ForeignKey('Topic', related_name='following', blank=True, null=True)

class Topic():
    name = CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    source = CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)



User.objects.filter(~Q(messages__topics__in=F('following'))
).values('id').annotate(missing_topics=Count('following__topics', distinct=True))
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant models?

Comment: I added the relevant models.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this in a single query. But if you have many more users than topics (like stackoverflow has), you could try looping over each  topic in order instead of each user to improve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using a subquery.

First, make sure `Following.topics` uses a different related name than `Messages.topics`.

```
class Following(models.Model):
    topics = ManyToManyField('Topic', related_name='following')
```

Then it should be possible to create a [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions). Something like this:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
user_following_topic = Topic.objects.filter(following__users=OuterRef('pk'))
User.objects.exclude(messages__topics__in=Subquery(user_following_topics.values('pk')))
```

This might not work and give you your expected output exactly as written, but I think the principle should work for your case as well.

On the other hand, I don't really understand your database structure. It seems you use m2m relations where foreign keys could be more appropriate and simpler. The more complicated your relations are, the harder it is to create this kind of advanced query. And queries with lots of database joins can be very slow, since they might have to process huge amounts of data, compared to simple queries.

For example, instead of using m2m realitions, `Following` would make more sense to me like so:

```
class Following():
    topic = ForeignKey('Topic', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    duration = fields.DateRangeField(blank=False, null=False)
```

So basically a "through" model, as explained in the [django docs on model relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) where there's a similar example.

Comment: I suppose it would be clearer if I called "Following": "FollowingGroup".  I was trying to create an association of groups of users all following the same sets of predefined topics on the following object.  In your example I'd have to create a follwing object for each user for each topic they're following and I was attempting instead to create a group of topics being followed by a group of users.  Which is likely what you mean for me to use with a through model?  I would set the many to many through following for topics?

Comment: Well. The way m2m works, every m2m relation will result in an extra table anyway. With a "through" you can add extra columns to that table. And since it's a django model, you can add custom methods for the model and manager/queryset.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean by "group of users following a group of topics". There's no right way to organize your database and relations, but there are lots of advantages to keeping it as simple as possible. Your model code is just 14 lines of code, but it will result in 8 database tables.

Comment: If I'm understanding your use of subquery correctly, that would return all users with messages that contain the topics the user is following.  I am looking for all users with messages that have ALL topics the user is following.

Comment: Perhaps I have worded my question badly.  I found another question today that my question is potentially a duplicate of. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138623/django-query-for-many-to-many-subset-containment

Comment: Yeah. You probably would have to modify the code in my answer. I think you should be able to get where you want with the subquery approach. But I'm not sure if I can create a solution that gets you the exact result you want, since I would need to start up a django project with a database and dummy data to really test it out myself.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  If I'm able to do it using your approach I'll update my question to reflect the new models.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be ok, unless someone else also submits an answer based on the original question. If you edit the question so that answers no longer make any sense, then there's no point. :)